# Mysql.connector blocks execution

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector

When I try to use mysql.connector in python, nothing happens, the terminal freezes and nothing happens infinitely

```
import mysql.connector
hostname = '********.mysql.database.azure.com'
username = '***************.mysql.database.azure.com'
password = '*******'
database = '*********'
port     = 3306

print("Hello World");
try:
    # conn = mariadb.connect(
    conn =  mysql.connector.connect(
        user=username,
        password=password,
        host=hostname,
        port=port,
        ssl_ca="BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem"
    )
    print("Connection established")
except:
    print("Error")
```

```
C:\Users\Nathan Almeida\Documents\workspace\research-api>python connection.py
Hello World
```

[Imagem com o codigo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5uau.png)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved

I took a look at the mysql documentation and found mysql.connector.MySQLConnection.
I changed mysql.connector.connect to mysql.connector.MySQLConnection and it worked.

But I still don't understand why mysql.connector.connect doesn't work and freezes the terminal.